# How to run a script multiple time parallel using tollef parallel

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a script that receives no argument and output something to stdout. I want to execute it like this

```
 php script.php >> output.txt
```

And I have a `parallel` program installed in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine. I think it's not GNU parallel since the manual is different to the GNU parallel's.

Using the `parallel` program I can do it like this

```
$parallel -j 4 -- 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt'
```

It basically runs all the `'php script.php >> output.txt'` commands in 4 parallel jobs.

Let's say I want to run the script 100 times. I tried using bash for loop.

```
commands=''; for i in {1..100}; do commands+=" 'php script.php >> output.txt'"; done; parallel -j 4 -- `echo $commands`
```

But it returns a lot of errors.

```
sh: 1: sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Syntax error: end of file unexpected
sh: 1: script.php: not found
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 1: script.php: not found
sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 1: sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
script.php: not found
```

But when I output the `$commands` to the screen (`echo $commands`) and append to `parallel -j 4 --` it runs normally.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: can you try with `echo "${commands}"`?

Comment: nope, still error. dunno why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many trials, I found that I can put bogus arguments for the command executed by `parallel`.

By rereading the manual, I found that there are two ways to use `parallel`

```
parallel [options] [command] -- [argument ...]
parallel [options] -- [command ...]
```

Beside using it like below (as example in my question)

```
$parallel -j 4 -- 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt' 'php script.php >> output.txt'
```

I can do it also like this

```
$parallel -j 4 php script.php >> output.txt -- 1 2 3 4 5
```

The `php script.php >> output.txt` will executed 5 times because of the `1 2 3 4 5`. The text `1 2 3 4 5` will act as argument, but since the command doesn't receive argument, it will still be executed 5 times.

So the final command will be like this.

```
args=''
for i in {1..100}; do
    args+=' $i';
done;
parallel -j 4 php script.php >> output.txt -- $args
```

I tried this one, and it works

```
petra@petra-laptop:~$ args=''; for i in {1..100}; do args+=' $i'; done; parallel -j 4 php script.php >> output.txt -- $args
petra@petra-laptop:~$ wc -l output.txt 
100 output.txt
```

even shorter

```
petra@petra-laptop:~$ rm output.txt 
petra@petra-laptop:~$ parallel -j 4 php script.php >> output.txt -- `for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done;`
petra@petra-laptop:~$ wc -l output.txt 
100 output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

I understand you do not have GNU Parallel installed, but if you had that you could do this:

```
seq 4 | parallel -N0 -j 4 php script.php >> output
```

-N0 = do not append an argument.

You would also avoid the racecondition that exists by having multiple commands append to the same file in parallel.

Comment: I'll keep in mind to install GNU Parallel instead of tollef parallel next time. Still curious about my question, though. But thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a word splitting issue - the quotes inside `$command` are being treated as literal instead of syntactical. Here is an example of this happening:

```
$ ls
file1  script
$ foo="'file1' 'script'"
$ echo foo
'file1' 'script'
$ cat $foo
cat: 'file1': No such file or directory
cat: 'script': No such file or directory
```

The single quotes are being treated as literals. Hence in your problem, instead of parallel being passed the command `'php script.php >> output.txt'`, it is being passed `'php`, then `script.php`, etc. Quoting the variable won't help, as it will then treat all 100 commands as a single word.

You should be able to use an array instead to avoid this:

```
commands=(); 
for i in {1..100}; do 
    commands[$i]=" 'php script.php >> output.txt'"
done; 
parallel -j 4 -- "${commands[@]}"
```

Comment: What if you remove the double quotes around `"${commands[@]}"`?

Comment: still gives error. but i just found an answer for this. thanks for the help. :)